# Whatsapp for UBUNTU Phone and Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, whatsapp

Has anyone tried to install **ubuntu watsapp for phone and touch** following the instructions at this link http://www.whatsappfor.org/software/whatsapp-ubuntu-phone-touch/ ?
It seems a little complicated. I would try it on BQ Aquaris 4.5 R22 but Im little worried...
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It is not an officially supported client. WhatsApp have been banning such clients, and anyone who uses them. If you want WhatsApp on Ubuntu, the best thing to do is to contact WhatsApp directly and make it known to them that people want it on Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi Dobey, im using telegram instead watsapp and it works fine. Watsapp was my previous app in android and most of my contacts are using it. Now its more clear in my mind that i have to use telegram for a long time... thanks for the answer.